# How to add a MIME type with a project created in Quickly?

Tags: development, application-development, quickly, mime-type

I've built an application I want to release however I would like the files to open with the application.

I have modified the .desktop file accordingly, however quickly seems to have no option for MIME files and I don't have a clue how to add them.

(Also, I'm not sure if this belongs here, because it's a developer question but Quickly was made by Ubuntu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add mime types to a system by using [xdg-mime](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/xdg-mime.1.html).

```
command line tool for querying information about file type handling and adding 
descriptions for new file types
```

Command to add a new mime type:
`xdg-mime install [--mode mode] [--novendor] mimetypes-file`

From the man page:

```
mode: can be user or system; for system you need root permissions.
```

```
install: Adds the file type descriptions provided in mimetypes-file to the
desktop environment.  mimetypes-file must be a XML file that
follows the freedesktop.org Shared MIME-info Database specification
and that has a mime-info element as its document root. For each new
file type one or more icons with name type-subtype must be
installed with the xdg-icon-resource command in the mimetypes
context. For example the filetype
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text requires an icon named
application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.text to be installed (unless the
file type recommends another icon name).
```

Alternatively you could use the [ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes) on mime types. This uses manual instructions to edit in this text

`gksudo gedit /etc/mime.types`

and to edit it something like

`text/extension                   extension`

This editing of /etc/mime.types can also be accomplished with the command line stream line editor [`sed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/sed.1.html) but I would suggest using xdg-mime.

Comment: Thanks, I also found some more information for packages `data_files=[('/usr/share/mime/packages', ['one-click-installer.xml'])],` is added to the setup.py