# Adding mime type

Tags: packaging, deb, mime-type

Hello i'm creating an ide called SLY.
Sly creates .slyproj files i want that when user click on it they see the file icon, and sly must open up!

i asked on the IRC i made sly.sharedmimeinfo : http://paste.ubuntu.com/915799/ (in first row ? is missing i now)

and i've added dh_installmime -i to my rules file

sly.desktop: http://paste.ubuntu.com/915941/

Then i packaged the .deb but nothing happened to .slyproj files (i can't see the icon)

--EDIT:

i edit sly.sharedmimeinfo: paste.ubuntu.com/916010 now when i double click on .slyproj i can't see icon but it says that no application is found for opening .slyproj

**NOW IT WORKS WHEN I CLICK .slyproj SLy open ups! I only can't see file icon...**

Comment: For adding mime types: see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/46030/3940). To make Nautilus open your files with their default application: see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/q/71359/3940)

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/46020/how-to-add-a-mime-type-with-a-project-created-in-quickly

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/103594/mime-type-of-a-file

Answer (score 1):

See `/etc/mime.types` and `man mime.types`. Not sure how additional types get added by programs without editing the main file, that'll be an exercise for the OP. Good luck.

Comment: i edit sly.sharedmimeinfo: http://paste.ubuntu.com/916010/
now when i double click on .slyproj i can't see icon but it says that no application is found for opening .slyproj

Comment: Sorry, I only have time to point you in the right direction, not solve the problem for you.